# COALESCE on calculated column to remove NULL

Tags: sql, case, coalesce

The formula below works fine now. It gives a result of 1 when the calculation is above 4. The problem I am running into is trying to replace the `NULL` with `COALESCE` / zero. I have a tried a few options and the syntax keeps breaking.

```
CASE 
    WHEN CEILING(ORDER_QTY * 1. / BOUM * 1.) > 4 
        THEN 1
END AS 'ABOVE TARGET'
```

Comment: Simply `ELSE <othervalue>`?

Comment: What does 'remove the NULL' mean? do you want the rows with the null result for 'above target' to be eliminated from the results, or the rows returned but the null values replaced with something like 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ELSE` portion of a `CASE` expression defaults to `NULL` if you don't state something else explicitly.

You should choose what you want to have instead of `NULL`, like so:

```
CASE 
    WHEN CEILING(ORDER_QTY * 1. / BOUM * 1.) > 4 
        THEN 1
    ELSE 0 --Here
END AS 'ABOVE TARGET'
```

Either that or you should put your logic in a filter if you a trying to only see rows that are 'above target', ie.:

```
WHERE CEILING(ORDER_QTY * 1. / BOUM * 1.) > 4
```